# Broad jumps with Hopscotch in Changeling: the Dreaming

Tags: world-of-darkness, changeling-the-dreaming

my question is about WayFare 1, Hopscotch.

Description says:

> Leap trods in a single bound! With this cantrip, the changeling can
>   make herself or others venture (seemingly) impossible leaps, either up
>   or down. This cantrip is limited by the amount of space available (she
>   could not smash an enemy into the ground as she could with Gimmix).

It should clearly mean that you can only go **up and down** (by Y-axis).

But then follows description of successes:

> 1 success — Five feet straight up; 15-foot broad jump.
>   2 successes — One story straight up; 30-foot broad jump.
>   3 ...

So that should mean that you can make horizontal jumps (by X-axis).
My questions are:

1. You really can jump horizontally?
2. Can you control how high and how
   far you jump?
3. Can you make large horizontal leaps without jumping
   high?
4. Do you receive damage from jumping (second phase of jumping is surely falling and 10 stories straight down is a pretty painful distance to fall)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. **Yes**, you can jump horizontally (which will, I think, always include a bit of verticalyity as well): see the description of successes you yourself have quoted.
2. **Yes**, you can control it. Witness: "The number of successess determines how far the caster **can** leap." The RAW doesn't say "will leap", it sets a maximum distance that you can't exceed, but you can surely control and pick your destination within the range.
3. **Yes**. To simplify things, imagine a rectangle in front of you, whose size is determined by your successes. You must stay within that rectangle when picking your destination -- and I think that's all the RAW declares. However, a bit of realism probably comes into the picture: it's rather unlikely that you could jump forward without a bit of Y-axis movement... though **it will depend on your Storyteller as well, for magic is magic, and your campaign may even allow that.**
4. Again, return to the rectangle: if you arrive on a solid spot within the rectangle (which, following the introductory description -- "impossible leaps, either up *or down*" -- extends downwards as well, meaning: 1 success: five feet straight up or five feet straight down, that is, you have 10 feet on the Y axis, but you start from its middle)... so, where was I :), **if you arrive on a solid spot within the rectangle you're okay**, there's no damage. **If you end up in the air** (or similarly non-solid spot) (we're talking Changeling and Dreams here), **you'll receive falling damage indeed**, calculated from that spot (but I'd advise leaving exact physics with momentum etc out of the game.)

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, you really can. The phrase "leaps, either up and down" in this case refers to the starting and ending position: you could both jump up to a rooftop or down into a crevasse using Hopscotch.
2. Well, your die roll controls how high and how far you jump, as per the success table, but within those guidelines, and presuming you have the right Realm for it, sure. (Note that you could, with Actor or Fae, cause someone *else* to make that jump.)
3. No. A broad jump is basically a low arc; your fifteen-foot broad jump is going to have a high point of five feet and so on.
4. No. Part of the magical effect is that the target makes the trip safely. Otherwise, you could use it as a cantrip catapult, and that's out of the scope of a first-dot power.